# How to work multiple Hibernate Properties file for lazy loading?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, lazy-loading, dto

I want to build an application where i use the same Hibernate Objects but using multiple Hibernate properties file. For example, person 1 might only want columns 1-3 on table 1 while person 2 want columns 1,5-6 on table 1.

How do i dynamically load different configurations (if person 1 is using the app or person 2) depending on the user? Is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different mapping files for this. You can handle this at the code level. You can introduce a Object to Entity and vice-versa conversion layer in your project.

Depending on which user logs in you can only get/set those fields.

For ex:

```
if (user.equals(user1)) {
        domainObj.setColumn1(entityObject.getColumbn1);
        domainObj.setColumn2(entityObject.getColumbn2);
        domainObj.setColumn3(entityObject.getColumbn2);

    }

    if (user.equals(user2)) {
        domainObj.setColumn1(entityObject.getColumbn1);
        domainObj.setColumn2(entityObject.getColumbn2);
        domainObj.setColumn3(entityObject.getColumbn3);
        domainObj.setColumn4(entityObject.getColumbn4);
        domainObj.setColumn5(entityObject.getColumbn5);
    }
```

Comment: what if i dont want to create custom domainObj unless it is the same one? even if it is the same one can i not do the manual mapping? Can't it auto map? Because following your recommendation i would need the setter for every user.

Comment: Your dominObj (DTO) is just a duplicate of Entity. You can use the same domain Obj for all types of user. My suggestion just moves the "various hibernate mappings" that you are thinking of to the code. There could be a way to maintain different mapping files in hibernate.

Comment: you would need above logic for each category of user.